# What is the difference between using px and not in HTML?

Tags: html

What is the difference between using px in html for a width/height and not using px?

Ex:

```
<div width="90"></div>
```

vs

```
<div width="90px"></div>
```

Comment: I just tried it out and there should be no difference because width-attribute does not apply do `div` anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the element, sometimes there might be no difference & `px` will be assumed by default.

In other situations, like with `<img />`, `px` is the only supported unit, and so, you just need to put the integer without the unit (see Attribute->width [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img)).

In your case, you probably shouldn't be using `width` attribute on a `<div>` at all since it's depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use the width attribute on `<canvas>`, `<embed>`, `<iframe>`, `<img>`, `<input>`, `<object>`, and `<video>` tags where the value should just be an integer. For any other tags such as the `<div>` used here, the width attribute has been deprecated. You should use CSS for anything regarding the layout and appearance of your document.